# JDBC Insert batch working different on SqlServer and Oracle

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, batch-file, jdbc

I am trying to do a batch insert on SqlServer and Oracle, implemented in the following test code:

```
public class TesteBatch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Connection con = getConnection();
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    PreparedStatement psInsert = criaPs(con);

    Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 50000; i++) {
        try {

            psInsert.setInt(1, i);

            psInsert.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(time.getTime()));
            psInsert.addBatch();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro inserindo " + i);
        }
    }

    try {
        int[] executeBatch = psInsert.executeBatch();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(executeBatch));
        psInsert.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e.getUpdateCounts()));

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static PreparedStatement criaPs(Connection con) {
    try {
        return con.prepareStatement("insert into tester values (? , ?)");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@BI_ENS:1521:xe";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,"xxxx", "xxxx");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

The code inserts data into a Tester table that has a primary key ID and a timestamp.

What i want to do is to insert into the database in a way that even if some data on the batch is already there the data that is not there gets inserted, a BatchUpdateException is thrown because the primary key constraint is being violated.

I am testing with a batch with 50.000 entries, where 50% of it is already in the database.

With SqlServer it works as intended, the exception is thrown but the data that is not duplicated is still inserted into the database, in the end all 50k registry are on the database.

It doesnt work on Oracle though, the exception occurs and nothing in the batch is inserted, even the data that doesnt exists on the database. In the end only 50% of the batch is there.

Can someone explain why this is happening on Oracle? Is there a way to make it work like it does on SqlServer?

Thank You Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

According to oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28767 that's the way oracle processess batches:

> Note:
>   The execution of the batch always stops with the first element of the batch that generates an error.